# What would happen to a wizard / a witch if they never find out they can do magic?

Tags: harry-potter

For instance, what would have happened to Harry if the Dursleys never told him anything, if he never received a letter from Hogwarts, or if no one ever told him he was a wizard? Would he just live his live wondering why he sometimes does something strange?

Comment: Harry was a unique case and muggle borns are identified by the ministry / hogwarts - so they will, at some point, find out

Comment: @NKCampbell - This assumes that they're in the UK, after the invention of the Quill of Acceptance. What about before? What if they're overseas?

Comment: the question would need narrowing then eh? That all sounds too broad :)

Answer (score 2):

Since the founding of Hogwarts it is highly unlikely that any wizard has gone unrecognized due to the [The Quill of Acceptance and The Book of Admittance](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-quill-of-acceptance-and-the-book-of-admittance).

> **At the precise moment that a child first exhibits signs of magic**, the Quill, which is believed to have been taken from an Augurey, floats up out of its inkpot and attempts to inscribe the name of that child upon the pages of the Book ...

It is from this list of names that acceptance letter are sent out. We have no reason to believe there would be a circumstance in which a letter would not be sent. Even in the case of a Muggle-born a school representative travels to the home to explain to the parents what is going on.

Even though attendance at Hogwarts is [not compulsory](https://web.archive.org/web/20070313175302/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/faq_view.cfm?id=91) I would imagine that the Wizarding World would not want an Obscurial developing (no matter how small the risk. Considering Harry's guardians were not wizards there would not be an opportunity for them to home-school; although I suppose they could have sent Harry to a different school like Draco had mentioned about himself.

Therefore I think the [final outcome](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/123857/what-if-the-parents-of-a-muggle-born-witch-or-wizard-refuse-to-let-them-attend-h?rq=1) remains the same. The Wizarding World convinces the parents/students one way or the other to attend a magical institution.

Answer (score 0):

When the Dursleys didn't give Harry his letter, the Ministry sent more letters. And more letters. Eventually, Harry couldn't *help* but get his letter. It's reasonable to assume that other Muggle parents who try to prevent their child from getting the letter would find themselves in a similar situation.